# How can I create an abstract Host property in a T4 template base class with VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t4

I created a base class to use with a T4 template, in an assembly separate from the assembly where the template exists.   In the base class I need to access the Host property.  This property is added to the generated class.   So I added an abstract property so that I would not get compilation errors in my base class.

```
public virtual global::Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.ITextTemplatingEngineHost Host { get; set; }
```

I get a build warning:

> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingD0A29F1F828173770AF28F0494709F7D.GeneratedTextTransformation.Host' hides inherited member 'MyProject.TextTransformationBase.Host'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.

I get a runtime error:

> Error 2   Running transformation: System.Exception: Host property returned unexpected value (null)

It appears that in VS2012 they added the hostSpecific="trueFromBase" attribute to the template directive and I am assuming this resolves this specific use case.  I was wondering if there was a workaround in VS2010.

Perhaps by using a different private property name in the base class and accessing the Host property using reflection at run time might be a way to get around this.  I just wanted to see if there was a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

```
private ITextTemplatingEngineHost _host;
private ITextTemplatingEngineHost HostProperty {
    get
    {
        if (_host == null)
        {
            _host = (ITextTemplatingEngineHost)this.GetType().GetProperty("Host").GetValue(this, null);
        }
        return _host;
    }            
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is what we did before TrueFromBase was available.